# Python 3.8: Placing large dictionaries on SSD for processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have some background code which loads two pickle files, compares/combines them and then saves the result. The files are rather large, a couple hundred MB. So the process uses a fair amount of RAM. I do not really care how long the comparison takes but my RAM is quite limited and I like to do other things in the meantime. Is there a way to place the tmp_data dictionarys on the SSD while editing them or edit a pickle file in place? Or some other way to save RAM?

My current code:

```
import pickle

tmp_data=pickle.load( open(file0, "rb" ) )
tmp_data1=pickle.load( open(file1, "rb" ) )

#check and compare    
for tmp_id in tmp_data1:

    #check if already there
    if tmp_id in tmp_data:

        #check if the same
        if tmp_data[tmp_id] != tmp_data1[tmp_id]:
            #do some comparison job
            tmp_data[tmp_id] = my_compareFunction(tmp_data[tmp_id],tmp_data1[tmp_id])
    else:
        tmp_data[tmp_id] = tmp_data1[tmp_id]

pickle.dump(tmp_data, open(outfile, "wb+" ))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to save RAM in this case, sorry.

I have noticed though that you open() files, but not close them. This is *very* bad practice. Always close your files. Two possible approaches to fix this would be:

```py
with open(file0,"rb") as f:
    tmp_data=pickle.load(f)
```

or

```py
f=open(file0)
tmp_data=pickle.load(f)
f.close()
del f #you don't have to delete the variable,
      #it's just good practice to limit the amount of globals
```

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks for the tip! I assumed that pickle.load(open(file0, "rb" )) would be equal to the with version. I will change that.